# Referring to author order on paper when arXiv and published copy are different

Tags: citations, mathematics, arxiv

A paper that I need to refer to reasonably often has in its arXiv version the authors listed alphabetically by surname (as is the custom in mathematics). The published version lists the authors in a different order, having moved the last author to second place. The last author in the published version is  recently told me he doesn't understand why people keep insisting on using the published author order (or to put it bluntly: why they keep listing him last).

What would be the correct way to refer to the joint work, given that the arXiv version is no less prominent than the published version? (Other than in the bibliography, where I would stick to the published order) I'm not sure whether it is more accurate to talk about the work/results of ABCD or of ADBC.

Comment: I consider the published version to be more prominent than the arXiv version, because it is clear who reviewed the published version, but unclear whether anyone reviewed the arXiv version.

Comment: I would use the order corresponding to which version you cite. Thus, use the arXiv order if the citation is to the arXiv appearance and use the published order if the citation is to the published version.

Comment: @user2768 the two versions are identical up to journal branding. And I don't know what you mean by "who reviewed the published version" : refereeing is anonymous.

Comment: @Dave I would cite both version simultaneously in the sense of giving both the journal reference and the arXiv  number. The arXiv version is the same, and free to read.

Comment: I would actually cite both versions, with cross-references between the two.  "[1] Alpher, Bethe, Gamow, and Deltoid. Twinkle twinkle little star. Preprint, October 2009.  Arxiv:0980.1234 [astro-ph.CO]. Preliminary version of [2]." followed by "[2] Alpher, Gamow, Bethe, and Deltoid. Twinkle twinkle little star. _J. Shiny Objects_ 14(3):123–194, 2010. Archival version of [1]." Ink is cheap.

Comment: @DavidRoberts the published version remains more prominent, because it is clear that it has been peer-reviewed. (Even though the arXiv version is identical, it is unknown whether it has been peer-reviewed. To discover that the reader needs to know about the peer-reviewed version and know that both versions contain the same material.) By "who reviewed the published version" I was referring to anonymous reviewers of the journal/conference/...

Comment: @JeffE since the OP has stated the two versions are identical, I'd suggest merging the two citations: [2] Alpher, Gamow, Bethe, and Deltoid. Twinkle twinkle little star. J. Shiny Objects 14(3):123–194, 2010. Also available as arxiv:0980.1234. (Ink might well be cheap, but the reader's time is not. The single citation hopefully suggests the versions are identical, whereas multiple citations might indicate distinct content.)

Comment: @user2768 But the two versions are *not* identical; they have different author orders! And it’s impossible to tell which of the author orders is “correct”, so I won’t (and shouldn’t) try. Thank Alpher et al. for wasting the readers time (or the reader for actually _reading_ the bibliography(?!)), not me.

Comment: @JeffE the documents aren't completely identical. The orders are different, the formatting is different, and no doubt the content is different too. (Any suggestion that you're wasting people's time was unintended! Your comments/answers are of high-quality.) The author ordering is entirely unimportant for me. Albeit, the ordering used in the main body should correspond to the ordering in the bibliography. This is where the problem arises.

Comment: @User2768 the content is identical, up to the journal branding and the author order.

Comment: @DavidRoberts, yes, you've said that, but are you sure? Is it possible that a colleague or an editor made a change? Have you verified that? For these reasons, your readers cannot be sure that the two versions are identical and no one has the time to check.

Comment: (That said, I'm usually more inclined to trust the technical report version, which hasn't been touched by an editor, because that version is how the authors wanted me to read it, rather than how the editor thinks I should read it.)

Comment: Does it matter...?

Comment: Either it's an error in the journal, or I'll be suspicious of the soundness of the paper. Why would two identical papers have different author order unless the authors, who clearly don't speak to each other, send without consulting the others have changed the order of authors on their own mind? (That's why I always try to stick with alphabetic ordering. It shows pettiness otherwise).

Comment: I'm not suspicious of the soundness of the paper, @Dilworth, since I understand the results myself, have generalised them in my own work, and know at least three of the authors personally. I don't know why this happened.

Comment: Unless it's a mistake, then something is seriously wrong here: either the contribution is distributed evenly between authors or not. Having identical papers with different author orders shows that one of these publications is falsely representing the contribution of authors.

Comment: @Dilworth in mathematics the usual practice is to list alphabetically, whatever the various contributions. There is no magic position (first author, last author etc). That is why the situation is odd.

Comment: @DavidRoberts, yes. That's precisely what I said: something is deeply odd here.

Answer (score 4):

As Aaron Montgomery's answer states, if you use the full author list in the text, it should match the author list in the bibliography. However, with four authors, you're usually in a position where you can just say

> A *et al.*

in the text rather than

> A, B, C, and D

or

> A, D, B, C

Comment: I find this trick particularly useful when writing A *et al.* [1,2], where [1] A, B, C, and D ..., and [2] A, D, B, and C ...

Comment: This is really unfair to B, C, and D.

Comment: Writing "A et al" in a field that (usually!) uses alphabetical order of authors is not a good practice.

Comment: Are there a lot of papers in such fields that have lots of authors?

Comment: Three- and four-author papers are more common now in mathematics than they used to be.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: At some point, writing out a long list of authors for completeness's sake doesn't seem like a good practice, either. I would try to refer to that paper obliquely.

Comment: In this paper alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/Main_Theorem.pdf I refer to a result of "Alon-Kleitman-Lipton-Meshulam-Rabin-Spencer."  It is rare but not unheard of for math papers to have more than six authors.  But I have never seen a paper in pure mathematics with so many authors that it would add any significant length to one's paper to list all the names in full.

Comment: I agree with @PeteL.Clark here, though I've had publishers change such references to "Alon, et al." in the copy-editing (even with only three authors).

Answer (score 3):

I would defer to the order in the version that shows up in your bibliography, presuming that one of those made it in. If not, or if you're somehow citing both, I personally would use the peer-reviewed ordering, but I doubt anyone would quibble either way.

Comment: _I doubt anyone would quibble either way_ one of the authors is, as I noted in my question.... And I would stick the arXiv reference _with_ the published version in my bibliography as a matter of principle, since it is a freely available copy: there's no reason to cite both separately.

Comment: I mean, if you're worried about personally offending one of the authors, I suppose you have your answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably an error on the part of the journal.  This happened to us once on a four author paper, because the journal got confused because they typeset 4-author papers in a 2-by-2 grid and then messed up the bibliographic information when they read it off the grid.  We’ve tried to get it fixed, but it’s essentially impossible.  Go with the version that the authors have control over.

Comment: Didn't think of that. I could ask A, the senior author (coincidence in this case that they are alphabetically first) if that happened.

Answer (score 2):

I have spoken with D, who was placed in second position in the author listing for the published version without their knowledge. They've said they don't mind me referring to the paper placing them last, as in the arXiv version. I'm not going to hack BibTeX to fiddle with author order in the citation keys, but if I use the authors in a sentence I will use "A, B, C and D".